# Mvel dynamic expression

Tags: mvel

Do you know if it's possible to dynamically evaluate an expression with Mvel. For example :

```
VariableResolverFactory functionFactory = new MapVariableResolverFactory();
MVEL.eval("def SUM(op1,op2,op3) { result=0B; if(op1) result+=op2; else result+=op3; }  return result; ",functionFactory);

ParserContext ctx = new ParserContext()
Serializable s = MVEL.compileExpression("SUM(op1,op2,op3)", ctx);
contextMapFct.put("op1", "5 > 3"); // just as an example if it's useless
contextMapFct.put("op2", new BigDecimal(10));
contextMapFct.put("op3", new BigDecimal(30));
Object obj= MVEL.executeExpression(s, contextMapFct, this.functionFactory);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few changes done

1.) Brace added at the last, was closing before `return result;`.

2.) `int result=0`, declaration added.

3.) `if(op1 == 'true')`, it is not coming as `boolean`, but as `String`

```
VariableResolverFactory functionFactory = new MapVariableResolverFactory();
MVEL.eval(
        "def SUM(op1,op2,op3) { int result=0; if(op1 == 'true') result+=op2; else result+=op3;   return result; }",
        functionFactory);

ParserContext ctx = new ParserContext();
Serializable s = MVEL.compileExpression("SUM(op1,op2,op3)", ctx);
Map contextMapFct = new HashMap();
contextMapFct.put("op1", "5 > 3"); // just as an example if it's useless
contextMapFct.put("op2", new BigDecimal(10));
contextMapFct.put("op3", new BigDecimal(30));
Object obj = MVEL.executeExpression(s, contextMapFct, functionFactory);
System.out.println(obj);
```

**output**

```
30
```

Comment: i am confused, the if statement should always be true in this case because 5 > 3 so the output should be 10 instead of 30 ?

Comment: ok it works after i removed the quote around the 'true' ! Thank you